# How to delete a macOS installer from Big Sur?

Tags: macos, trash

I downloaded the Mojave installer from my Big Sur machine to create a USB installer for an old Mac Mini.

I then deleted the installer from the Applications folder, but now whenever I try to empty the trash I get the error that it can't be deleted because it's in use:

[image: Can't delete macOS installer error]

I've also tried using the "Delete immediately" option when right-clicking on the item in the trash. Then I get this error:

[image: Delete immediately error]

When checking the permissions, I should be able to delete it:

[image]

So how can I delete this installer?

Comment: There may be a disk image inside it that's mounted (/"attached"), or something like that. You could probably track it down, but it might be simplest to reboot, and see if it's still "in use" after that.

Comment: I've rebooted many times and AFAIK there are no mounted images.